# Python keep prompting until valid

Tags: python

I am writing a script for prompting for a username. Username needs to be 3 or more and 10 or less characters in length. I want to refactor the code using while instead of repeating to prompt.

```
def hint_username(username):
    if len(username) < 3:
        print("Invalid Username, minimum of 3 characters")
        myUser = input("Please enter username: ")
        hint_username(myUser)
    elif len(username) >10:
        print("Invalid Username, maximum of 10 characters")
        myUser = input("Please enter username: ")
        hint_username(myUser)
    else:
        print("Valid Username")

myUser = input("Please enter username: ")
hint_username(myUser)
```

Comment: Be careful, it looks like you're mixing multiple variable naming conventions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this as so with a `while` loop. I would not recommend recursively calling a function to validate user input.

```
def invalid_username(username):
    return not 3 <= len(username) <= 10


myUser = input("Please enter username: ")
while invalid_username(myUser):
    myUser = input(
        "Invalid username! Username must be 3 to 10 characters.\n"
        "Please enter username: "
    )

print("Valid Username")
```

[Example code in Python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20invalid_username%28username%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20not%203%20%3C%3D%20len%28username%29%20%3C%3D%2010%0A%0A%0AmyUser%20%3D%20input%28%22Please%20enter%20username%3A%20%22%29%0Awhile%20invalid_username%28myUser%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20myUser%20%3D%20input%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Invalid%20username!%20Username%20must%20be%203%20to%2010%20characters.%5Cn%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Please%20enter%20username%3A%20%22%0A%20%20%20%20%29%0A%0Aprint%28%22Valid%20Username%22%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=1&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)